# OpenSSL with stream_socket_accept on PHP

Tags: php, sockets, openssl

I'm trying to use SSL in my socket client-server application.
And for some reason I'm getting the following response:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Unable to set private key file
```

I can write and read from the file.

I use the following code to retrieve the data:

```
$socket = stream_socket_accept($this->server);
stream_set_blocking($socket, true);
stream_socket_enable_crypto($socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv3_SERVER);
$data = fread($socket, 1024);
stream_set_blocking($socket, false);
fclose($socket);
```

Here's my server init:

```
$this->server = stream_socket_server(self::SERVER_ADDRESS, $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND | STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $this->ssl->getStreamContextForSSL());
stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->server, false);
```

Context:

```
public function getStreamContextForSSL() {
    $context = stream_context_create();
    $this->setContextSSLOptions($context, array(
        'local_cert' => self::PEM_FILE,
        'passphrase' => self::PEM_PASSPHRASE,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false
    ));
    return $context;
}
```

Comment: What OS are you using for this application.

Comment: I use Windows. I've got openssl and php paths in system PATH. And got OPENSSL_CONF with a path to config. Config is pregenerated by XAMPP.

Comment: It seams you are trying to run the script in your ssl path instead where the script is.

Comment: What do you mean? Working directory is where the script is.

Comment: Same problem there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809682/error-using-ssl-cert-with-php

Comment: It's not the case. I'm running it from the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to check if your private key is valid, because php realisation of OpenSSL doesn't tell you in case it isn't.